# Does PyQt5/pyqt4 already supports QtVirtualKeyboard with Handwriting Recognition?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5, qtquick2

I'm working on a desktop application using pyqt5, and I want to use a Virtual Keyboard with Handwriting Recognition. I saw that Qt, QtVirtualKeyboard already support it.

Here's [a link](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2016/03/02/qt-virtual-keyboard-updated-with-handwriting-recognition/)!

[image]

I got the C++ Qt example code running on QtCreator. 
But using python3.5 and PyQt5 it gives this message:

```
module "QtQuick.VirtualKeyboard" is not installed 
 import QtQuick.VirtualKeyboard 2.1
```

How should I go on from here?
Does PyQt5 comes with VirtualKeyboard module? if no How to install it on PyQt5?

Answer (score 5):

for qt desinger you can add only this line on your .py file.

```
os.environ["QT_IM_MODULE"] = "qtvirtualkeyboard"
```

but **If you want use QML** with qtvirtualkeyboard;

There is no virtualkeyboard plugin in pyqt5.8, you must be use qt's paths.

For a example, basic steps for pyqt5, qt5.8 and qtvirtualkeyboard installiation on ubuntu:

1.step install qt5.8 with qtvirtualkeyboard

> wget
>   http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.8/5.8.0/qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.8.0.run
>
> chmod +x qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.8.0.run
>
> ./qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.8.0.run

2.step

> apt-get install python3 python3-pip
>   pip3 install pyqt5

3.step

set environmental variables your qt paths on your python code.

```
import sys, os
os.environ["QT_DIR"] = "/opt/Qt5.8.0/5.8/gcc_64"
os.environ["QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH"] = "/opt/Qt5.8.0/5.8/gcc_64/plugins/platforms"
os.environ["QT_PLUGIN_PATH"] = "/opt/Qt5.8.0/5.8/gcc_64/plugins"
os.environ["QML_IMPORT_PATH"] = "/opt/Qt5.8.0/5.8/gcc_64/qml"
os.environ["QML2_IMPORT_PATH"] = "/opt/Qt5.8.0/5.8/gcc_64/qml"
os.environ["QT_IM_MODULE"] = "qtvirtualkeyboard"

#print(os.environ) 

from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtQuick import *


class keyboardapp(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.view = QQuickView()
        self.view.setObjectName("View")
        #self.view.setFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.view.setSource(QUrl("main.qml"))
        self.view.setResizeMode(QQuickView.SizeRootObjectToView)
        #self.Screen = self.view.rootObject()
        #print("Screen(Root) = " + str(self.Screen))
        self.view.show()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
test = keyboardapp()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3):

I been stuck with this too, and i am new to Qt
After some researching, and digging in source code, found the solution

You dont need to import it to use it since its a module it will implement itself to every qt input

Well you dont need to install it on PyQt5 but on Qt5 if it is not already come with your Qt package, if you use archlinux you can install it with pacman

```
pacman -S qt5-virtualkeyboard
```

If you cannot find it in you os repositories try to build it here is documantation
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtvirtualkeyboard-index.html

Then to use it in your pyqt application, set environmental variable `QT_IM_MODULE` to "qtvirtualkeyboard" either from your bash or inside the top your script like

```
import os
os.environ["QT_IM_MODULE"] = "qtvirtualkeyboard"
```