# How can I integrate a Qt Virtual Keyboard with PyQt 5.8?

Tags: qt, keyboard, pyqt5, raspberry-pi3

I am using PyQt5.8 on a raspberry Pi 3, my application had a login form. So how can i prompt a virtual keyboard when user touchs one of the form fields in the touchscreen?

I tried [this](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/579118-pyqt-touch-input/) but it does not working with pyQt5 after porting it (it work fine with pyQt4), making the cursor in the field does not prompt the virtual keyboard.

Best regards!

Comment: This link could help you.[Use of qt virtual keyboard in pyqt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40360033/does-pyqt5-pyqt4-already-supports-qtvirtualkeyboard-with-handwriting-recognition)