# Install QtVirtualkeyboard in raspberry-pi?

Tags: python, pyqt5, python-3.7, raspberry-pi4, qtvirtualkeyboard

I am try to implement Qt-Virtualkeyboard in Raspberry- pi, using [PyQt5 - Show virtual keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62473386/pyqt5-show-virtual-keyboard) but I did'nt find the prefix path for it, bin, plugin etc folder, actually whole Qt folder doesn't exist.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In [my previous solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62473386/pyqt5-show-virtual-keyboard) I used the Qt binaries officially provided but not compatible with the RPI architecture so you have to compile it:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install git build-essential
sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5 qt5-default qtdeclarative5-dev libqt5svg5-dev qtbase5-private-dev qml-module-qtquick-controls2 qml-module-qtquick-controls qml-module-qt-labs-folderlistmodel
sudo apt-get install '^libxcb.*-dev' libx11-xcb-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libxrender-dev libxi-dev libxkbcommon-dev libxkbcommon-x11-dev
git clone -b 5.11 https://github.com/qt/qtvirtualkeyboard.git
cd qtvirtualkeyboard
qmake 
sudo make
sudo make install
```

Comment: NOW is working good!..  but unfortunately , once keyboard appear on screen make invisible the app in background.. did you solve it @eyllanesc ?

Comment: @Gaston Try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63963718/6622587

Comment: Wow.. so fast @eyllanesc Thank you for help... i will check your suggestion link. I guess we are working in a similar project with Touch screen + Yocto + Arm Core .. is it?...