# Qtvirtualkeyboard only working in main window not in additional windows

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtvirtualkeyboard

I'm running a PyQt5 (5.15.9) application with Python 3.11.2 on a Raspberry Pi 4B (Raspberry Pi OS 64-bit Debian Bookworm) with connected touchscreen.

Qtvirtualkeyboard is working perfectly fine on all text inputs of my main window. However, I have an additional window, that opens when a button is clicked, but qtvirtualkeyboard is not working on the text input fields of this second window. When a text input field is focussed, the keyboard shows up, but is not responsive nor is any text inputted when keys are pressed.

I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63719347/install-qtvirtualkeyboard-in-raspberry-pi/63720177#63720177) to install qtvirtualkeyboard and used the example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63963718/6622587) to include it in my application.

Minimal example of my code (the function "handleVisibleChanged" is used as suggested in the linked answer above):

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic

def handleVisibleChanged():
    if not QtGui.QGuiApplication.inputMethod().isVisible():
        return
    for window in QtGui.QGuiApplication.allWindows():
        if window.metaObject().className() == "QtVirtualKeyboard::InputView":
            keyboard = window.findChild(QtCore.QObject, "keyboard")
            if keyboard is not None:
                area = window.geometry()
                area.moveTop(int(keyboard.property("y")))
                window.setMask(QtGui.QRegion(area))
                return

class MyApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    '''Main window'''

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('ui-file.ui', self)
        self.second_window = SecondWindow()
        self.button_for_second_window.clicked.connect(self.second_window.show)
        self.show()

class SecondWindow(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    '''Second window that opens when a button in MyApp is clicked'''
    
    def __init__(self):
        super(SecondWindow, self).__init__()
        # Load second window UI, that has QLineEdit
        uic.loadUi('second-ui-file.ui', self)
        self.setWindowModality(Qt.ApplicationModal)  # Disable main window when open
```

My app is run with the following piece of code (UI created with QtDesigner):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.environ["QT_IM_MODULE"] = "qtvirtualkeyboard"
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    QtGui.QGuiApplication.inputMethod().visibleChanged.connect(handleVisibleChanged)
    ex = MyApp()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

What am I missing here?
Any hints or suggestions are highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem:
I had the following line in the instance for the second window:

`self.setWindowModality(Qt.ApplicationModal)`

This should disable the main window, while the second window is open. However, it also disables the qtvirtualkeyboard input, which is actually quite logical now....