# Using virtual keyboard with PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, windows-10, virtual-keyboard

I have a touch screen monitor. I have followed these steps to enable virtual keyboard on my UI: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62522005/19949085 It is working with my main UI. I am able to use it to enter the user name and password. [my main UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrHbi.png)

When i push the login button i close the main window and open another window. Second window is also contain a text box. Virtual keyboard appears in the second window but does not sense any input. How to use virtual keyboard with my all windows?

Windows 10 -
Python: 3.10 -
PyQt5: 5.15.2

I have followed these steps to enable virtual keyboard on my UI: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62522005/19949085